# convert javascipt array to an object

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer, apify

in javascript , how can I convert a nested array to an object , for example , I have this array :

```js
let Input_Array=[[key1,value1],[key2,value2],[key3,value3]]

//The output Object , should be like this : 

let Output_Object ={
    key1 : value1,
    key2 : value2,
    key3 : value3,
}
```

I guess that we will not have problem in values because we can just copy them by index by input_Array[i][1] .
The issue is in keys , because if we have a key===string , must follow the pattern of an object variable .

if you any idea how to trait it , or is there a library for doing this it's better .

Answer (score 3):

Use [`Object.fromEntries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) to turn a 2d array into an object.

```js
let Input_Array = [
  ['key1', 'value1'],
  ['key2', 'value2'],
  ['key3', 'value3']
]

let Output_Object = Object.fromEntries(Input_Array);

console.log(Output_Object);
```

Answer (score 1):

you should use  [Bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors)

maybe this would help

```js
const array = [["name", "john"],["age", 22]];
let object = {};

array.forEach((value) => {
  object[value[0]] = value[1];
})

console.log(object)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use reduce method to turn convert your array to the wanted object:

```js
const Input_Array = [['key1','value1'],['key2','value2'],['key3','value3']];


const result = Input_Array.reduce((a,c) => ({...a, [c[0]]: c[1] }), {});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Initialize a new object, then iterate over the input array and insert the values into the object explicitly.

```js
var Input_Array=[["key1","value1"],["key2",2],[3,"value3"]];

var Output_Object = {};

for (var i = 0; i < Input_Array.length; i = i + 1) {
  Output_Object[Input_Array[i][0]] = Input_Array[i][1];
}

console.log(Output_Object);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const Input_Array = [["key1", "value1"],["key2", "value2"],["key3", "value3"]];
const Output_Object = Input_Array.map((elem) => ({[elem[0]]: elem[1]}));
console.log(Output_Object);
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.